# Offline bootstrap

Tags: html, css

How can I make this work in offline? This is in my index.html:

```
<link href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.5/paper/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
```

Update:

There's a line in the css that contains http call to get the font css, do I 
need to download it offline as well?

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700");/*!
```

Comment: download bootstrap files :)

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/ Download bootstrap and put into your root folder and give the local link.

Comment: In the boostrap.css there's a line "@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700");/*!
" do I need to replace this with something offline?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Download the minified CSS file from Bootstrap and store it in an external CSS folder - then call it into the page as an external CSS resource

```
for example: 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Answer (score 2):

> Download Boostrap file and Save it.
>
> https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/download/

**basic syntax :**

```
<link href='Path/yourNameFile.css' rel='stylesheet'>
```

> Path is interpreted relative to the source of the Html file.
>
> For Example : if Your bootstrap file is in Folder MyBootstrap and so This Folder and Html file are some Place,Your code must be like this :

```
<link href='MyBootstrap/YourNameFile.css' rel='stylesheet'>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use bootstrap files below in offline then just download these file on you PC.

1. Then remove text from https till just before the main file
2. Remove integrity & crossorigin attribute contents
3. Wolla! now you can see bootstrap files without CDN links.
4. The reference links & sheets wont work till you Remove integrity & crossorigin attribute contents.

Go ahead with this tip & tell me if it worked for you.
 i.e

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" >`

```
<script src="jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" ></script>
<script src="popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
```

Place the bootstarp files in the same folder with html files as you are giving the relative path. If you have saved bootstrap files in a folder the give `src="foldername/filename"` path.

Answer (score 1):

you have to download the css files and then use somethin like this

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

you can see more here: https://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://getbootstrap.com/ and download bootstrap put it in the same folder as your html and call it like this.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to download usable bootstrap js and css files on your local folder and use it, after that automatically increase your page speed.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `gavgrif's` answer you will also need the file at this:

```
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js
```

and this command to be pasted in  section:

```
<script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```